# Abort issue when error/exception occurs?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script which calls multiple scripts (bash & python) from some directories.

I would like to get it aborted when any of the script throws an error/exception.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/test.sh /usr/1/sample.sh /usr/2/temp.py 

exit 0
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this ?

FYI : I'm a beginner in bash scripting.

Comment: It all depends on the output and/or exit status of the scripts your script calls. Some programs output errors but keep running, some programs return an exit status of 0 for success and others return a non-zero success. Some programs output regular output to std error.

Comment: Also your code that calls multiple scripts, actually calls one script and passes the other two as arguments. I would search Google for bash scripting guides (there are some really good, easy to find guides) and read through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `set -e` at the top of the script:

```
   -e errexit       If not interactive, exit immediately if any
                    untested command fails.  The exit status of a com‐
                    mand is considered to be explicitly tested if the
                    command is used to control an if, elif, while, or
                    until; or if the command is the left hand operand
                    of an “&&” or “||” operator.
```

This will *only* work if one of your commands exit with an exit code of non-zero on failure. Well-behaved programs should always exit with 0 *only* on success, and if yours don't, you probably want to fix that.

I'm not entirely sure what you expect this to do:

```
/usr/bin/test.sh /usr/1/sample.sh /usr/2/temp.py
```

Since this will run one command (`/usr/bin/test.sh`) with two arguments, you probably want to put them on separate lines.